# Fail to upgrade Artifactory from version 6.x to 7.x

Tags: artifactory

I'm trying to upgrade my current artifactory 6.23.1 to 7.10.1
All upgrade logs are ok but when I restart the service I've the following errors:

```
[root ~]# cat /opt/jfrog/artifactory/var/log/console.log | grep ERROR  
2020-11-14T14:12:06.384Z [jfrt ] [ERROR] [bca759f3b3ef4148] [o.a.l.v.LoggingVersion:83     ] [ocalhost-startStop-2] - Error occurred while converting logback config for conversion: File '/opt/jfrog/artifactory/var/etc/artifactory/logback.xml' does not exist.  
2020-11-14T14:12:06.387Z [jfrt ] [ERROR] [bca759f3b3ef4148] [o.a.l.c.LoggingConverter:69   ] [ocalhost-startStop-2] - Failed to execute logging conversion.  
2020-11-14T14:12:20.353Z [jfrt ] [ERROR] [ea891217e8aa6df ] [d.c.m.ConverterManagerImpl:249] [art-init            ] - Conversion failed. You should analyze the error and retry launching Artifactory. Error is: The current Artifactory config schema namespace is 'http://artifactory.jfrog.org/xsd/3.1.2' The provided config does not seem to be compliant with it.  
2020-11-14T14:12:20.355Z [jfrt ] [ERROR] [ea891217e8aa6df ] [ctoryContextConfigListener:126] [art-init            ] - Application could not be initialized: The current Artifactory config schema namespace is 'http://artifactory.jfrog.org/xsd/3.1.2' The provided config does not seem to be compliant with it.  
2020-11-14T14:12:22.366Z [jfrt ] [ERROR] [                ] [o.a.w.s.ArtifactoryFilter:213 ] [http-nio-8081-exec-5] - Artifactory failed to initialize: Context is null  
2020-11-14T14:15:20.393Z [jffe ] [ERROR] [                ] [                              ] [main                ] - Error: Error starting application Failed pinging artifactory for 180Request failed with status code 404  
2020-11-14T14:15:20.397Z [jffe ] [ERROR] [                ] [                              ] [main                ] - exit code : 0
```

And the website is not working (error 500)
What can I do to solve this error ?

Answer (score 0):

Nicolas, it complains about 2 issues,

1.Logback.xml not in the place under $JFROG_HOME/artifactory/var/etc/artfactory location, use the find command to check the location of logback.xml

2. The Artifactory config complains about incorrect xsd values, can you tell me exactly from which version to which version the Artifactory is upgraded and the exact steps, as well as navigate to $JFROG_HOME/artifactory/var/etc/artfactory and open the artifactory.config.latest.xml and share the first 4 lines.

Comment: Hello Muhammed Kashif,  I'm trying to upgrade from version 6.23.1 to 7.10.6 1.  logback.xml is located in /var/opt/jfrog/artifactory/etc as artifactory.config files  2. The 4 first lines look like this: <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?> <config xmlns="artifactory.jfrog.org/xsd/2.2.9" xmlns:xsi="w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="jfrog.org/xsd/artifactory-v2_2_9.xsd"> <serverName>GDC1PDMLAPP001</serverName> <offlineMode>false</offlineMode>

Comment: Just change the second line <config xmlns...> tag from the value 2.2.9 to 3.1.2 like "<config xmlns="http://artifactory.jfrog.org/xsd/3.1.1" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.jfrog.org/xsd/artifactory-v3_1_1.xsd">" and restart the Artifactory.